# How can I access a specific collectionview child? In this case, the label "DataCadastroLabel"

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, parent-child

I want to change the value of VerticalOptions.

I can't directly access this label, even if I pass its name "DataCadastroLabel"

XAML

[image: XAML code]

C#

```cs
ItemsListView.DataCadastroLabel.VerticalOptions
```

Comment: We could not access it in this case as the label is in a DateTemplate . When did you want to change the value ? We could use data binding.

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images

Comment: items in templated controls cannot be accessed by name.  If you need to make changes at run time you should do it by binding the property to a viewmodel and modify the model properties.

Comment: Got it, thank you guys. These layout changes are only to adapt some components to the device's landscape mode

Comment: You can use [data-templates/selector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector) to config different template under landscape and portrait.