# How to add a calculated value to a CollectionView after it has been populated

Tags: xaml, .net-6.0, maui

I have the following `CodeBehind` and `XAML` which I used to get all data from an `SQLite` table and populate a `CollectionView`:

**.cs**

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    List<Record> records = App.RecordRepo.GetAllRecords();
    recordList.ItemsSource = records;
}
```

**.xaml**

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label x:Name="lblHoldingTotal" Text="Total"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblAverageBuyPrice" Text="Average Buy Price"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblTotalPaid" Text="Total Paid"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblTicker" Text="Ticker"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblHoldingValue" Text="Holding Value"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblProfit" Text="Profit"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</Grid>

<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <CollectionView x:Name="recordList">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Id}" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Amount}" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Paid}" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="3" Text="P/L" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding PurchaseDate}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</Grid>
```

How would I update the value in Column 3 (Which currently has `P/L` as a placeholder for all rows) based on a value from the `CollectionView` after populating it, and a value from a `Label` outside the `CollectionView` without using the MVVM framework?

For example:

`(Column 3 label text) = (Column 2 Label text value) - lblTicker.text`

Comment: you need to create a property in your VM that performs the calculation and bind your UI to that

Comment: @Jason,  How would I do that without using MVVM?  At the moment, I am trying to learn the CodeBehind way of doing things and will move to MVVM when I have more experience.

Comment: if you're using a templated control like CollectionView you have to use data binding

Comment: @oshirowanen I dont have enough information from your question to be sure if this will solve your problem but it sounds like you can get away with a regular binding + converter. Also, *do not* use code-behind to learn and then switch to mvvm. You'll have to unlearn a lot more than whatever learning you're going to get from code-behind. Code behind is reserved specifically for view only logic that's usually related to controls. If your data is involved in anyway, then as Jason mentioned, you need to do it through VM (you don't need full framework for it, just INPC is enough).

Answer (score 1):

We could not change the Column3 label text in the Codebehind way as it is set in the template of the **CollectionView**. We also cannot access the label in codebehind by setting **x:Name** to it. Try using data bindings. There are several similar cases that you could refer to: [How can I access a specific collectionview child? In this case, the label "DataCadastroLabel"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65919479/how-can-i-access-a-specific-collectionview-child-in-this-case-the-label-datac) and
[How to set a x:Name to a control in a CollectionView / ListView in Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69734382/how-to-set-a-xname-to-a-control-in-a-collectionview-listview-in-xamarin-forms).

Answer (score 0):

**How would I update the value in Column 3**

Make a custom class, that you use as the ItemTemplate.

Usage:

```xml
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <mynamespace:MyItemView ... />
    </DataTemplate>
</CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

The custom class'es XAML will be similar to what you have now inside `DataTemplate`, but with a header, like any other XAML file:

```xml
<Grid xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyNameSpace.MyItemView">
    ...
    <... x:Name="someElement" ... />
</Grid>
```

In that class, you can do anything you need when BindingContext is set:

```cs
public partial class MyItemView : Grid
{
    ...
      
    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();

        // The "model" that this row is bound to.
        var item = (MyItemClass)BindingContext;
        // The UI element you want to set dynamically.
        someElement.SomeProperty = item....;
        ...
    }
}
```

---

**Update a value from a Label outside the CollectionView**

In your page's code behind, its easy to set property values (that are not bound to items of a collection):

```cs
lblTicker.Text = "Whatever text is needed".
```

If you need something more than that, add "pseudo-code" (doesn't actually compile) to the question, that shows an example of what you are trying to do.